# What's the meaning of tsudzukeru in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

抑えきれぬ殺意に身を炊き続けるもの.

I know it means that someone has an uncontrollable intent to kill simmering within him but I'm not sure what the tsudzukeru means here

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: I know it means to continue but I don't understand it in this sentence

Comment: Isn't 炊き続ける a typo for 焼き続ける?

Answer (score 2):

This construction `[V ます-stem]-続ける` expresses the idea of “to continue to V” or “to continue V-ing”. The verb in this case is 炊く. Whatever is referred to by もの continues to burn or boil the body.